# MySQL dilemma: composite unique key across tables

Tags: mysql, unique-key

I am attempting to implement an "extension" table structure for some stats that I am gathering from multiple sources.

My "parent" table looks something like this:

```
`test_parent` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `actions` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

My first "child" table looks somethinglike this (eventually I will have a child table for each source):

```
`test_child` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `external_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `external_actions` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `test_parent_id` (`test_parent_id`)
)
CONSTRAINT `test_child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`test_parent_id`) REFERENCES `test_parent` (`id`)
```

All this will work fine in my implementation (I will be using Java/Hibernate); however, for the first child table I will need a composite unique key for external_id and date. I know that I cannot have a composite unique key across tables. I would rather not have one table to store all of the stats because the actual analytics I am collecting can vary greatly by source. I would be more open to getting rid of the "parent" table.

Is there some other way I can look at this problem? I am hoping to avoid using triggers to enforce uniqueness, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `date` in the child table if you want to establish a unique constraint on it with `external_id`.  You can *also* have `date` live in the parent table, and reference it via the foreign key.  That will allow you to support `date` differently by other child tables in the future.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_parent` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `actions` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `date`)
);

CREATE TABLE `test_child` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_parent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `external_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `external_actions` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `test_parent_id` (`external_id`,`date`),
  CONSTRAINT `test_child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`test_parent_id`, `date`) 
    REFERENCES `test_parent` (`id`,`date`)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the `date` field to the child table and declare a unique key:

```
ALTER TABLE child ADD UNIQUE INDEX parent_date (parent_id, `date`);
```

Comment: I'd rather not, all children would need date. But this can be a reasonable compromise between what I ideally want and completely axing the parent table.